# Shared Method to use in components in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

im having a problem writing a method in my angular project.
its a method which is used in 3 components. the main component, and 2 other child.
i created a service and export it and made the method public and thought it may work , but i remembered i have 3 datasources which are api's going to the server and i dont want to inject all 3 of'em into 4 (.ts) files(the service / and 3 other component). this is the method

```
public setDifferences(data){
//some logic here.

}
```

i thought making the `setDifferences` method an event but i dont think that would be a good idea.

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

As I understood right you have 3 controllers that uses a service. To make this service work you need 3 datasources that need to be passed to the service.

You have two possibilities for this solution. One is to inject the 3 datasource directly as service into the service, the other one is to inject the datasources into the component and pass it to the service method. I would prefer the first one.

Therefore you need to create 3 services, one for each datasource. Each of that service you inject it into the constructor of the service owning the `setDifferences` method.

```
DataSource1 --\                    /--> Component1
               \                  /
DataSource2 ----+---> Service ---+----> Component2
               /                  \
DataSource3 --/                    \--> Component3
```

Comment: That Was a great explanation. thank you very much. 
my question was not accurate enough but your answer was awsome. 
The solution i came up with is to write the ` setDifferences ` Method in my main component and for using it into other component make it an event so i can listen to it in other 3 . there was a mistake by me that i had to pass the datasources. i correct it and it does not need to pass all 3 of'em into each components and just needed to write it in the main. then do some logic on it in a method and pass the method into other components